# Is it possible to amplify near zero signals?

Tags: voltage, sensor, current, amplifier, signal

Is there an amplifier has an ability to amplify any signal down to -500 dBm?

If there is not, can it be possible?

If it is not possible, what is the weakest ever signal that can be amplified?

Comment: How many electrons/second into 50 ohms is -500dBm? I suspect, rather less than 1. Which would mean ... no. There are avalanche techniques (originally employed in photomultipliers) to amplify single electron signals. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electron_multiplier

Comment: I'd be more worried about the signal-to-noise ratio...

Comment: Nah, -500dBm into 50 ohms is about 11 years per electron, so why bother with S/N?

Comment: I suspect Planck's constant has a role in this calculation but I haven't quite put my finger on it yet.

Comment: Yep, there's a limit due to the uncertainty principle.

Comment: impdence may be less than 50 ohms ... that is not problem...even superconductor with near zero impdence can be used, but I dont know if the -500 dBm enough ? maybe must not less than -300 dBm or even -200dBm ?

Comment: According to one link I've found, the *minimum* noise temperature of a linear amplifier is \$T_{min} = \frac{h\nu}{k}\$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Opamps these days are darn good.  You can amplify the thermal (Johnson) noise of a resistor, with the amplifier only adding a fraction to the total. You can cool the resistor... but also cool the amps.  I'm not sure of the limits.  What's -500dBm in degree's K?

Comment: At liquid helium temperature (-269 C) with 1 Hz of bandwidth, the thermal noise would be -192 dBm.  To get to -500 dBm at that temperature would require a bandwidth of 10^-31, i.e. a timescale 10^13 times longer than the age of the universe.

Comment: Great, So 1K ~-200dBm and -500 is 10^-30 degree's K.  That's certainly well below what we can hope to measure then.  (A one Hertz bandwidth is about right, I don't want to wait much longer for a data point.) Thanks.

Comment: what about gps receivers wich can process signals at -168 dBm ?

why we cant find commircal amplifers reach this range ?

is processing easier than amplifiying ?

Comment: @manabduo, Sorry I don't do much RF stuff.  So 300K is about -174 dBm, (according to this, http://www.radio-electronics.com/info/rf-technology-design/noise/thermal-calculations.php)  -168 is 6dB above that.  So a quick search of mini-circuits shows noise figures of NF ~1.0dB.  That seems within the range you want.. But again I'm not an RF guy, and I find noise temperatures' and figures somewhat confusing... due to lack of experience.

Answer (score 0):

I've studied something called stochastic resonance as it applies to neurobiology, however it has applications in general signal processing. Basically, you apply a uniform noise generation to the signal you want to detect, and the idea is that the signal you want to generate will resonate with the noise and become more detectable. At a signal that low, I am unsure, but this is the only method I am aware of that helps with signal detection among very low signal to noise ratios.
For more information:

http://www.aps.org/publications/apsnews/199606/stochastic.cfm

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_resonance